# Passing arguments by reference

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, pass-by-reference

I want to ask if it is possible to pass arguments to a script function by reference:

i.e. to do something that would look like this in C++:

```cpp
void boo(int &myint) { myint = 5; }

int main() {
    int t = 4;
    printf("%d\n", t); // t->4
    boo(t);
    printf("%d\n", t); // t->5
}
```

So then in BASH I want to do something like:

```
function boo () 
{

    var1=$1       # now var1 is global to the script but using it outside
                  # this function makes me lose encapsulation

    local var2=$1 # so i should use a local variable ... but how to pass it back?

    var2='new'    # only changes the local copy 
    #$1='new'     this is wrong of course ...
    # ${!1}='new' # can i somehow use indirect reference?
}           

# call boo
SOME_VAR='old'
echo $SOME_VAR # -> old
boo "$SOME_VAR"
echo $SOME_VAR # -> new
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's 2018, and this question deserves an update. At least in Bash, as of Bash 4.3-alpha, you can use *namerefs* to pass function arguments by reference:

```
function boo() 
{
    local -n ref=$1
    ref='new' 
}

SOME_VAR='old'
echo $SOME_VAR # -> old
boo SOME_VAR
echo $SOME_VAR # -> new
```

The critical pieces here are:

- Passing the variable's name to boo, not its value: **`boo SOME_VAR`**, not **`boo $SOME_VAR`**.
- Inside the function, using **`local -n ref=$1`** to declare a *nameref* to the variable named by `$1`, meaning it's not a reference to `$1` itself, but rather to a variable *whose name* `$1` holds, i.e. `SOME_VAR` in our case. The value on the right-hand side should just be a string naming an existing variable: it doesn't matter how you get the string, so things like `local -n ref="my_var"` or `local -n ref=$(get_var_name)` would work too. `declare` can also replace `local` in contexts that allow/require that. See [chapter on Shell Parameters in Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html) for more information.

The advantage of this approach is (arguably) better readability and, most importantly, avoiding `eval`, whose security pitfalls are many and well-documented.

Comment: It would be useful to note which version of bash this was introduced in as I have an old version and do not have this feature.

Comment: The Interwebz are telling me this feature was introduced in Bash 4.3-alpha: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare.

Comment: Important catch is that neither the local name, nor any other local variable in the function, may coincide with the argument, because bash has no way of indicating you actually mean the variable from calling scope.

Comment: @Jan Hudec, sorry, your statement is contradictory. Did you mean that _any_ local name or local variable may collide with the referenced variable name? In that case, I believe, declaring all local references at the very beginning of the function boo effectively solves all issues.

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček my quick test suggests it does not help. That is, if the function has `local -n ref=$1; local some_var; …` and you call it with `some_var`, the reference will reference the local `some_var`, not the outer `some_var`, breaking the function and not doing what you expected (bash 5.1.16 here).

Comment: @JanHudec, alright. This behaviour is apparently already fixed in Bash 5.2.15 from Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček … which is way newer than that comment.

Answer (score 25):

From the Bash man-page (Parameter Expansion):

```
    If the first  character of parameter is an exclamation  point (!), a
    level of variable indirection is  introduced. Bash uses the value of
    the variable  formed from the rest  of parameter as the  name of the
    variable; this variable  is then expanded and that value  is used in
    the rest  of the  substitution, rather than  the value  of parameter
    itself. This is known as indirect expansion.
```

Therefore a reference is the variable's name. Here is a `swap` function using
variable indirection that does not require a temporary variable:

```sh
function swap()
{   # 
    # @param VARNAME1 VARNAME2
    #
    eval "$1=${!2} $2=${!1}"
}

$ a=1 b=2
$ swap a b
$ echo $a $b
2 1
```

Answer (score 17):

Use a helper function `upvar`:

```
# Assign variable one scope above the caller.
# Usage: local "$1" && upvar $1 value [value ...]
# Param: $1  Variable name to assign value to
# Param: $*  Value(s) to assign.  If multiple values, an array is
#            assigned, otherwise a single value is assigned.
# NOTE: For assigning multiple variables, use 'upvars'.  Do NOT
#       use multiple 'upvar' calls, since one 'upvar' call might
#       reassign a variable to be used by another 'upvar' call.
# See: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference
upvar() {
    if unset -v "$1"; then           # Unset & validate varname
        if (( $# == 2 )); then
            eval $1=\"\$2\"          # Return single value
        else
            eval $1=\(\"\${@:2}\"\)  # Return array
         fi
    fi
}
```

And use it like this from within `Newfun()`:

```
local "$1" && upvar $1 new
```

For returning multiple variables, use another helper function `upvars`.  This allows passing multiple variables within one call, thus avoiding possible conflicts if one `upvar` call changes a variable used in another subsequent `upvar` call.

See: http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference for helper function `upvars` and more information.

The problem with:

```
eval $1=new
```

is that it's not safe if `$1` happens to contain a command:

```
set -- 'ls /;true'
eval $1=new  # Oops
```

It would be better to use `printf -v`:

```
printf -v "$1" %s new
```

But `printf -v` cannot assign arrays.

Moreover, both `eval` and `printf` won't work if the variable happens to be declared `local`:

```
g() { local b; eval $1=bar; }  # WRONG
g b                            # Conflicts with `local b'
echo $b                        # b is empty unexpected
```

The conflict stays there even if `local b` is `unset`:

```
g() { local b; unset b; eval $1=bar; }  # WRONG
g b                                     # Still conflicts with `local b'
echo $b                                 # b is empty unexpected
```

Answer (score 15):

I have found a way to do this but I am not sure how correct this is:

```
Newfun()
{
    local var1="$1"
    eval $var1=2
    # or can do eval $1=2 if no local var
}

var=1
echo  var is $var    # $var = 1
newfun 'var'         # pass the name of the variable…
echo now var is $var # $var = 2
```

So we pass the variable name as opposed to the value and then use eval ...

Answer (score 14):

Bash doesn't have anything like references built into it, so basically the only way you would be able to do what you want is to pass the function the name of the global variable you want it to modify. And even then you'll need an `eval` statement:

```
boo() {
    eval ${1}="new"
}

SOME_VAR="old"
echo $SOME_VAR # old
boo "SOME_VAR"
echo $SOME_VAR # new
```

I don't think you can use indirect references here because Bash automatically accesses the value of the variable whose name is stored in the indirect reference. It doesn't give you the chance to set it.

Comment: thats what i figured, but being new to bash it seemed weird that to pass the variable as if "by reference" you have to pass the quoted variable name ...

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so this question has been waiting for a 'real' solution for some time now, and I am glad to say that we can now accomplish this without using eval at all.

The **key** to remember is to declare a reference in both the caller as the callee, at least in my example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE this does require a bash version >= 4.3

set -o errexit -o nounset -o posix -o pipefail

passedByRef() {

    local -n theRef
    
    if [ 0 -lt $# ]; then
    
        theRef=$1
        
        echo -e "${FUNCNAME}:\n\tthe value of my reference is:\n\t\t${theRef}"
        
        # now that we have a reference, we can assign things to it
        
        theRef="some other value"
        
        echo -e "${FUNCNAME}:\n\tvalue of my reference set to:\n\t\t${theRef}"
        
    else
    
        echo "Error: missing argument"
        
        exit 1
    fi
}

referenceTester() {

    local theVariable="I am a variable"
    
    # note the absence of quoting and escaping etc.
    
    local -n theReference=theVariable
    
    echo -e "${FUNCNAME}:\n\tthe value of my reference is:\n\t\t${theReference}"
    
    passedByRef theReference
    
    echo -e "${FUNCNAME}:\n\tthe value of my reference is now:\n\t\t${theReference},\n\tand the pointed to variable:\n\t\t${theVariable}"
    
}
```

Output when run:

```
referenceTester:
        the value of my reference is:
                I am a variable
passedByRef:
        the value of my reference is:
                I am a variable
passedByRef:
        value of my reference set to:
                some other value
referenceTester:
        the value of my reference is now:
                some other value,
        and the pointed to variable:
                some other value
```

Answer (score 2):

Eval should never be used on a string that a user can set because its dangerous. Something like "string; rm -rf ~" will be bad. So generally its best to find solutions where you don't have to worry about it.

However, eval will be needed to set the passed variables, as the comment noted.

```
$ y=four
$ four=4
$ echo ${!y}
4
$ foo() { x=$1; echo ${!x}; }
$ foo four
4
```

Comment: but can you use it to set the variable, i.e. ${!x}=5

Comment: Indirection can be almost as bad as eval when it comes to user input because bash processes expansions indirectly. `f() { local x=${!1}; }; f 'a[$(echo hi >&2)]'`. Just have to make sure the input is never handled as arithmetic, which in Bash can be harder than most people realize.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

append_string()
{
if [ -z "${!1}" ]; then
eval "${1}='$2'"
else
eval "${1}='${!1}''${!3}''$2'"
fi
}

PETS=''
SEP='|'
append_string "PETS" "cat" "SEP"
echo "$PETS"
append_string "PETS" "dog" "SEP"
echo "$PETS"
append_string "PETS" "hamster" "SEP"
echo "$PETS"
```

Output:

```
cat
cat|dog
cat|dog|hamster
```

Structure for calling that function is:

```
append_string  name_of_var_to_update  string_to_add  name_of_var_containing_sep_char
```

Name of variable is passed to fuction about PETS and SEP while string to append is passed the usual way as value. "${!1}" refers to contents of global PETS variable. In the beginning that variable is empty and contens is added each time we call the function. Separator character can be selected as needed. "eval" starting lines update PETS variable.

Comment: There's no point in using `eval` here anymore. As of Bash 4.x, using named references is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me on Ubuntu bash shell

```
#!/bin/sh

iteration=10

increment_count()
{
  local i
  i=$(($1+1))
  eval ${1}=\$i
}


increment_count iteration
echo $iteration #prints 11
increment_count iteration
echo $iteration #prints 12
```