# How to process values from for loop in shell script

Tags: shell

I have below for loop in shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

#Get the year 
curr_year=$(date +"%Y")

FILE_NAME=/test/codebase/wt.properties

key=wt.cache.master.slaveHosts=

prop_value=""

getproperty(){

    prop_key=$1

    prop_value=`cat ${FILE_NAME} | grep ${prop_key} | cut -d'=' -f2`
}
#echo ${prop_value}

getproperty ${key}

#echo "Key = ${key}; Value="${prop_value}

arr=( $prop_value )

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do 

echo $i  | head -n1 | cut -d "." -f1

done
```

The output I am getting is as below.

```
test1
test2
test3
```

I want to process the test2 from above results to below script in place of 'ABCD'

```
grep test12345 /home/ptc/storage/**'ABCD'**/apache/$curr_year/logs/access.log* | grep GET > /tmp/test.access.txt
```

I tried all the options but could not able to succeed as I am new to shell scripting.

Comment: you can change the fonction call to be a bit cleaner

getproperty(){
return `cat ${FILE_NAME} | grep ${1} | cut -d'=' -f2`
}

prop_value=getproperty ${key}

i am not sure to understand what you want to do, just add

Comment: echo $i | head -n1 | cut -d "." -f1 can be replaced by ${i%%.*}

Comment: @Froggiz Shell functions can't `return` strings.

Comment: Can you show us a sample input file? And you are trying to do what with the results of the first script? Run `N` commands of the second form with each output value in place of `ABCD`?

Comment: @Froggiz Unless you want to use [pass by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14852461/2908724).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- surely you can use less code to demonstrate the limitation more clearly and succinctly (and in a self-contained way, to boot).

Comment: That said, there are a bunch of bugs here you might want to fix yourself first; run through http://shellcheck.net/ and address what it finds.

Comment: ...also, if this is a "how can I do X?" question, does X really have anything at all to do with the code you gave us, other than determining its input values? There are a bunch of bugs in what you're doing already -- `arr=( $prop_value )` is horrid practice; look at what happens when your value contains a `*`, for instance -- but those bugs are probably not actually that closely related to what you're actually asking for.

Comment: Also, are your `*`s in your sample code for emphasis, or are they literal, or are they some mix of the two?

Comment: getproperty(){ echo cat ${FILE_NAME} | grep ${1} | cut -d'=' -f2 } prop_value=$(getproperty ${key}) like that it can ! return can be use for if statement

Comment: That code's *wrong*. Again, run it through http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: `getproperty() { cat "$FILE_NAME" | grep -F "$1" | cut -d= -f2; }; prop_value=$(getproperty "$key")` would be a little less wrong -- at least it doesn't have string-splitting and glob expansion where you don't want them.

Comment: BTW, the curly braces in `getproperty ${key}` do nothing at all to improve correctness -- it has the exact same bugs that `getproperty $key` has, which `getproperty "$key"` fixes.

Comment: As an aside, FILE_NAME should by convention have at least one lower-case character. See conventions for naming environment variables (and thus shell variables, with which they share a namespace) in the fourth paragraph of the relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html.

Comment: Also: `cat $filename | grep` is silly; much more efficient to run `grep <"$filename"`, giving `grep` a direct handle on the file rather than making it read from a pipeline from a separate process holding the handle. But, if you *must* make useless use of cat, at least make it `cat "$filename" | grep`, to avoid string-splitting and glob-expanding the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the many bugs elsewhere and focusing on the one piece of code you say you want to change:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do 
  val=$(echo "$i" | head -n1 | cut -d "." -f1)
  grep test12345 /dev/null "/home/ptc/storage/$val/apache/$curr_year/logs/access.log"* \
    | grep GET
done > /tmp/test.access.txt
```

Notes:

- Always quote your expansions. `"$i"`, `"/path/with/$val/"*`, etc. (The `*` should *not* be quoted on the assumption that you want it to be expanded).
- `for i in $prop_value` would have the exact same (buggy) behavior; using `arr` buys you nothing. If you want using `arr` to increase correctness, populate it correctly: `read -r -a arr <<<"$prop_value"`
- The redirection is moved outside the loop -- that way the second iteration through the loop doesn't overwrite the file written by the first one.
- The extra `/dev/null` passed to `grep` ensures that its behavior is consistent regardless of the number of matches; otherwise, it would display filenames only if more than one matching log file existed, and not otherwise.