# How to assign value to parameters of a function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am very new to shell. I need to return multiple values from a shell function that's why I am sending the arguments as parameters to the function like we do in programming languages like C using pointers.
I am calling the function like this

```
splitDate $date day month year
```

here day month & years are the variable in which I want to store the values.
My function definition looks like this

```
splitDate(){
    export IFS="/"
    declare -a var
    index=0
    for word in $1; do
        var[ $index ]=$word

        ((index++))
    done

    $2=${var[0]}
    $3=${var[1]}
}
```

When I run this I get this error "day=theValueIWant: command not found" &"month=theValueIWant: command not found" 
Whats wrong here?
test case : If i provide 04/05/2017 as date
I expect day to store 04, month to store 05 & year to store 2017

Comment: Can you provide a verifiable example with actual values ? An input and expected output?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540298/bash-passing-arguments-by-reference/2852445#2852445)

Comment: Are you really sure that's what you want?  Printing the output as a sequence of tokens so you can capture it to variables with `set --` or whatever would probably sit better with the overall design of the shell.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `read`. The arguments to `read` are the names of the variables to populate, which can be produced by parameter expansion just as well as by hard-coding them.

```
splitDate(){
    if [[ $1 != ??/??/???? ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "Date not in dd/mm/yyyy format" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    IFS=/ read -r "$2" "$3" "$4" <<< "$1"
}
```

which raises the question, do you really need a separate function?

```
# splitDate "$currentDate" day month year
#         vs
# IFS=/ read -r day month year <<< "$currentDate"
```

Comment: `++` for demonstrating simplicity again. Would this have been possible if I split `$1` into an array with `/` de-limiter and trying to define other parameter values from the array using `declare` and not using `eval`?

Comment: You could; I was going to post something like `IFS=/ read -a var <<< "$1"; declare "$2=${var[0]}"; # etc`, along with `printf -v "$2" '%s' "${var[0]}"`, until I realized neither did anything that `read` couldn't do just as well.

Comment: Was trying out the same as `splitDate(){

   local dateValues=( ${1//-/ } )
   declare "$2=${dateValues[0]}"
   declare "$3=${dateValues[1]}"
   declare "$4=${dateValues[2]}"
}
` for the function and called it as `splitDate "$(date  +"%d-%m-%Y")" day month year` but was not able to make it work. may be I was missing something here.

Comment: @chepner thanks for suggestion. This works!! I am not getting what its doing. Can you please extend it for handling an edge case like if the date is 04/05/2012 but user enters it as 0 4/05/2012.

Comment: That's not an edge case; that's your user not using the function properly.