# Bash keep track of variable in function

Tags: bash, function, scope, zsh

Full non-working code:

```
change_git=''

function cd() {
  change_git=''
  builtin cd "$@"
}

function git_info() {
  if [ -z $change_git]; then
    local st=$(bash -c "git symbolic-ref HEAD" 2> /dev/null)
    local bn=${st#refs/heads/}
    if [[ ! -z "${bn// }" ]]; then
      change_git="branch is: ${st#refs/heads/}"
    fi
  fi
  echo $change_git
}

PS1=$'Dir git status: $(git_info)'
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

The git branch should be cached in the `change_git` variable until the directory is changed. However, that doesn't happen and the variable is calculated every time.

Since I would like to print this to prompt, this causes the prompt to be slow (hence my reason for caching). And yes, prompt is faster once I remove this code, and is hence how I know that it is executed everytime.

Also, this is in **zsh**. And yes, I am also using oh-my-zsh.

Finally, please do not ask me to replace `bash -c "git symbolic-ref HEAD"` with just `git symbolic-ref HEAD`. I am using WSL and sharing git from Ubuntu to my Windows; and I am using MSYS2 as main terminal.

Comment: Where do you set it to a non-empty string?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I edited the question (its set to non-empty string after successful check of it being empty).

Comment: I just tried it. The first time I run `x` it says `execute`, when I run it again it says `dont execute`.

Comment: I have edited the question to add a non-working example. Sorry about not doing that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways to reach the behavior that you have described.

- 1) share a global variable in your different functions but not the
  most sexy
- 2) use the return code of your function to set/reset your  `myvar=x()`
- 3) you can also pass the variable by reference

http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference

[Bash - Passing arguments by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540298/bash-passing-arguments-by-reference)

Comment: Could you please demonstrate an example on how to use 1st option? I tried using `export` but failed. Its a string value so return code wouldn't work. 3rd option seems too complicated for my use case.

Comment: export could only be used to make the variable name available to any subshells forked from current shell. however, once the subshell have been forked. The subshell will have a new copy of the variable and the value, any changes to the exported variable in the shell will not effect the subshell.

Comment: Have a look at that link where all the variable declarations are defined http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-variables

Answer (score 0):

Your second version is very different from the first, because you're not echoing different things in the two cases.

When `$myvar` is empty, you do:

```
test=$myvar # sets $test to empty string
myvar='something'$myvar # sets $myvar to 'something'
echo `$myvar$test` # echoes 'something'.
```

When `$myvar` is not empty, you do:

```
echo $myvar$test # echoes 'something'
```

You never get `somethingsomethingsomething` because the only time you append `$myvar` is when `$myvar` is empty, and then you're appending an empty string. And `$test` is always an empty string because you're just copying the empty `$myvar` to it.

Comment: Thanks (sorry for the unhelpful examples, I had a synapse failure scripting 2 am in morning). I figured out (or deducted) my problem is probably because I have commands in `.bashrc` so its probably something to do with commands being launched in subshell and variables not carrying on. The examples worked in normal scripts, but dont seem to work in my .bashrc for some reason (maybe I need to figure out something else).

Comment: `.bashrc` isn't run in a subshell, it's sourced in your shell.

Comment: Maybe you should post the actual code, instead of all this "something" stuff.

Comment: I have posted actual code (gonna loose grade for this since its part of my project, but I would like to know the answer, more importantly). Also, I just switched to zsh, same results though.

Comment: You need a space before `]` in `if [ -z $change_git]; then`