# Bash reference variable by string name

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple function that checks whether a variables is declared and non empty or not.

```
my_var="dummy_val"

function validate_var(){
        ${1:?"Variable is not set"}
}

validate_var my_var
validate_var my_var2
```

I get the following error:

> script: line n: my_var: command not found

Is there a simple way I could reference the variable from the function argument?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35412000/9072753

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to solve the current issue, just for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. It uses the `!` variable indirection.

```sh
function validate_var(){
    : ${!1:?"$1 is not set"}
}
```

Comment: If `var` is set to empty string, it shows `bash: !1: var is not set`

Comment: I don't know what the expected output is for that case. Maybe validate the input first.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variable by prepending a `$`. Also I've added an `echo` (as an example), otherwise your validate_var function tries to execute it's argument:

```sh
my_var="dummy_val"

function validate_var(){
        echo ${1:?"Variable is not set"}
}

validate_var $my_var
```

Comment: With this solution I get "invalid variable name", even if the variable is declared as empty string (e.g. my_var2="").

Comment: Also, this passes "dummy_val" to the function, instead of "my_var".

Comment: It seems to work fine with an empty string: `$ my_var2=""
$ validate_var $my_var2
bash: 1: Variable is not set
`

Comment: You mean you want to pass a [variable by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540298/passing-arguments-by-reference)?

Comment: Actually, you're right. It does work, I don't know what I was doing wrong. Anyway, @choroba's answer does exactly what I want. Thanks.